# Ubuntu-Tweak user folder assignments are not persistent

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I have always used Ubuntu Tweak to set my default user folders (download, pictures, documents etc.)

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, the changes that I make to my user folders are not persistent, i.e., I have to reassign them using Ubuntu Tweak on every boot.

If it's helpful, two of the folders (music & video, if it matters), which are assigned to an external USB hard drve, do actually persist. The rest are on the internal HD and do not.

If anybody has experienced this issue or has any guidance I'd be grateful. I have hunted for answers to this question and found very little useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the use of Ubuntu-Tweak.

Simply create or modify the `user-dirs.dirs` file in `~/.config`.

This is the default file:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Simply change the folders to your custom ones and logout and in again.